# Spring Integration - Design - Prevent Infinite Processing Loop

Tags: spring-integration

I have a spring integration flow where a processor (scheduled) sequentially reads messages from a queue (jms) and attempts processing. If the processor finds that the message can't be processed until another event finishes, it sends the message back to the original queue and attempts processing later.

If it just keep sending messages that can't be processed, back to the queue, it creates an infinite loop.

So I need to hold onto them until I finish reading all messages in the queue that already exist. And trigger a release when all existing messages are read, before sending them to the queue. How do I go about this?

Note that I don't want to aggregate the messages, but just temporarily hold them, and somehow. Also note that my processor is scheduled to read messages (not message driven).

Answer (score 1):

In this case you have to acknowledge those messages in the queue anyway and re-send them back to it using `JmsTemplate` (or `JmsSendingMessageHandler`).

The feature with dequeue that the failed message is returned to the head of the queue. That's how you see it again and again and don't reach other messages (also you can do that with the concurrency).

With the resending messages in case of failure back to the queue, you place them in the tail of the queue. So, "bad" messages will be available later, after processing other, existing messages.

Comment: You could also publish them to a different queue and, periodically, run a task to move them back to the original queue.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I did. Just synchronously hold the unprocessable msgs in temp Q, and when I am done with the batch, kick off another task that moves them back into the holding Q. Thnx for the input you both, as always.